# How to insert a post into a page in wordpress? Using [Shortcodes]

Tags: wordpress, post, embed, shortcode

I am using wordpress as our CMS for our companies website.
We have about 5-10 pages which we want to insert the same call to action content in.

How can I create a shortcode that will allow me to embed the content from a post into a page?

Thanks
Steven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you'll probably want something along these lines:

```
function create_call_to_action_shortcode( $atts ) {
        $call_to_action_content = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $post_id, 'no_found_rows' => true ) );

        if( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19);

            $call_to_action_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );

            add_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19);

            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

        return $call_to_action_content;
}

add_shortcode( 'call_to_action', 'create_call_to_action_shortcode' );`
```

In your pages ( or other posts, for that matter ), you can simply insert `[call_to_action]` in the page/post content.

You can find more information on shorcodes [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). :)

**Edit:**

In order to remove sharing buttons from the post content, you need to call `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19);`. I've update the code above.

Comment: Thanks, but how to I set the page to get the content from? I have spent a few hours looking at shortcodes but many talk just about inserting custom html; whereas I want to insert a dynamic post into multiple pages. Thank you for this, I will have look soon.

Comment: I just think `[call_to_action]` needs an `id` or `slug` parameter... `[call_to_action id="43"]` would then display the content for that `id` or `[call_to_action slug="work"]` will display the content for a post with a slug `work`...

Comment: If he would like to pass a post id, I can give an example of how to parse the shortcode attributes. I was under the impression that there was a single post that would change ( content wise ), but remain the same post and, therefore, maintain the same post_id. If that's the case, just replace `$post_id` with the call-to-action-post's id.

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad it worked for you. Would you mind marking this as the answer? :D

Comment: I was about to. It does insert the post however it enables sharing options even when I have selected to have them removed for this post type.

Comment: That's because sharing must be enabled on the call-to-action post. Disable it there.

Comment: I have removed sharing on both pages, and sharing is disabled for pages. I am using Jetpack...    

I have also found that when I insert a page (this is so the page with the content doesn't appear on my blog index) it will work when logged in as admin, but when I am viewing the site when not logged in, it will display the last blog post. Very odd.

Comment: I'm not quite following here. Have you removed sharing for pages and posts or just pages? It's the post sharing that's probably getting you here. Also, I don't understand why you insert another page so **the page with content doesn't appear in your blog index**.

Comment: I want to have 10 pages with the content of one page inserted within each, so that I don't have to keep on updating each time I want to make a change. I have successfully inserted the content from one page into the other, however the jetpack sharing is activated (when I have specified it to be off for that page). It only inserts the correct page when I am previewing the site in admin, when I am logged out it will insert the latest blog post. You can see here: http://hunchbuzz.com/shortcode-test/

Comment: If you can only see it as an admin, the post is probably published privately. Be sure it's public and published, not just published.

Comment: Thanks for your input, both pages are public and have sharing turned off.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the sharing buttons issue. When you say both pages are public, are you saying the post with the call to action is as well? That's key here.

Comment: Sorry I can't see what you have updated... I am starting with two pages, one which will include the other. Both have sharing off and they are public.